# What was the earliest depiction of the angel/devil on your shoulder trope?

Tags: history-of, trope

What is the oldest depiction someone has seen of an angel on a person's shoulder advising him to do the right thing, and a devil on the same person's other shoulder tempting him toward an immoral act?

Comment: I'll bite. It dates back at least to 1947 with Little Lulu in [_A Bout with a Trout_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAqiS3zRUk8).

Comment: This is likely centuries or millennia old… there's an old Arabic folk or 'fairy creature' with a name which one might transliterate as "Wus-wus" who sits invisibly on your shoulder whispering naughty things to you.

Comment: Pushing it back to [1946](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038300/)!

Comment: And [_The Good Egg_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0430147/?ref_=tt_ch) in 1945.

Comment: And... in Christian, Islamic, and Buddhist works at least as early as the 2nd century AD. With an even older, similar simile in Plato's _Phaedrus_, written about 370 BC. Source: [Shoulder angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_angel) in Wikipedia.

Comment: "Donald's Better Self" from 1938? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0030068/

Comment: FYI Movies and TV have a [tag:first-appearance] tag.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GoodAngelBadAngel

Comment: Are you interested in the angel/devil trope in general, or specifically in moves/tv?

Comment: Related: The superstition of throwing a pinch of salt over the left shoulder when you've spilled it.  The idea was that the devil likes to gleefully watch the wastage of (then far more expensive) salt, and by throwing some over the shoulder, you're blinding him.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez- the trope in general.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron slight correction, in Islamic theology, the angels only record the actions. They don't tempt or advise.

Comment: Thank you, Mahm00d. You might want to correct the Wiki that I used as my source.

Comment: The best and most comprehensive modern example of this is in "Narbonic", which you'll have to read to see them in context, but graphic summary is here: http://narbonic.com/comic/shoulder-angels/

Comment: [Apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_angel#Origins), [_The Shepherd of Hermas_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shepherd_of_Hermas) is an especially old example.

Answer (score 34):

As comments have pointed out, the idea of having good and bad angels is ancient.

However, the literary work that popularised the trope is probably  Christopher Marlowe's play *The Tragical History of the Life and Death of Doctor Faustus*, commonly referred to simply as *[Doctor Faustus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Faustus_(play))*.  (Published somewhere between 1589 and 1592)

The play draws on a pre-existing legend, but introduced several new elements, including the good and bad angels.

> Synopsis
> ...
> Faustus instructs his servant Wagner to summon Valdes and Cornelius, a famous witchcrafter and a famous magician, respectively. Two angels, called the Good Angel and the Bad Angel, appear to Faustus and dispense their own perspectives of his interest in magic and necromancy. Though Faustus seems momentarily dissuaded, he is apparently won over by the Bad Angel, proclaiming, "How am I glutted with conceit of this" ("conceit" meaning the possibilities magic offers to him).
> ...
> When Faustus announces his intention to renounce magic and repent, Mephistophilis storms away. The good and evil angels return to Faustus: the Good Angel urges him to repent and recant his oath to Lucifer, but the Evil Angel sneers that Faustus will never repent. This is the largest fault of Faustus throughout the play: he is blind to his own salvation and remains set on his soul's damnation.

Comment: Was shoulder-standing involved, however?

Comment: The good and bad angels are stock characters in medieval [mystery plays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_play), which is where Marlowe got them from.

Answer (score 19):

An illustration for a 1468 edition of *City of God* (*De civitate Dei*) by Augustine of Hippo depicts angels and demons surrounding a writer, trying to influence what he writes. An angel floats above his left shoulder, and a devil stands by his right shoulder, both somewhat smaller than the human.

The image can be seen on [this stock photo site](https://www.agefotostock.com/age/en/details-photo/dispute-between-angels-and-demons-surrounding-a-saint-from-the-city-of-god-by-augustine-of-hippo-15th-century-abbeville-bibliotheque-municipale-library/DAE-11275014).

I found this in a [thorough answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/When-and-how-did-the-concept-of-a-devil-on-one-shoulder-an-angel-on-the-other-develop-Did-it-ever-appear-in-pre-20th-century-paintings) to a similar question.

Comment: Looking at the image, it is labeled as "angels and demons **surrounding** a saint". And yes, it is not AN angel and A devil, but a number of them. I don't think this is really a case "on your shoulder" but "pestering from all over the room".

Comment: One angel touching the saint's headdress, and a bunch of devils surrounding it. That's a different (though related) trope than what the question is asking about. (The label is misleading as it's just a single angel, but it has access to the saint and the devils do not.)